# Regular expression for words which end with e

Tags: regex, pcre

Why does `e$` does not match with words ending with `e`?
Example @ [`RegExr.com`](http://www.regexr.com/3bjh9)

Comment: e$ matches a line ending e, not particularly a word ending in e

Comment: Line or string ending. The later will be the case when using the `m` flag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct regex to find words ending with `e` is `e\b`.

- `$` denotes end of the line.
- `\b` denotes a word boundary.

[Check here.](http://regexr.com/3bjhc)

Answer (score 3):

Your expression does not match because `$` stands for the end of the string, or end of the line when used together with the `m` flag.

To match all words ending with e use: [`e\b`](https://regex101.com/r/uN0cA0/2) as suggested by miroxlav.

Sometimes a "words ending" can be open for interpretation, so you might want to add or remove characters to that definition depending on your case.
If so, you can use something like [`e(?=\s|$|[\.!'"\-:;\?\(\)])`](https://regex101.com/r/lZ8yC2/1), which won't accept `@` and some other characters as word endings.